# LED RGB in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm creating a model for our robot AISoy1 and I need to add its LED RGB on it. I'm trying to find robots using that, but I found nothing. I know it can be done in other simulators like Webots, do you know if that is possible in Gazebo?

If it isn't, how would you do that? I was thinking about showing a .png simulating the LED, one for each  of the basic colours...

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37527/led-rgb-in-gazebo/) by [Pablo Garcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/2741/pablo-garcia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably possible but you should ask gazebo questions on http://answers.gazebosim.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0